# Word - How to stick text to the bottom of page

Tags: text, ms-word, footer, mergefield

https://SURU.tinytake.com/sf/MTQxMTgzOV81MDc2MDI2

I want to stick some text of the bottom of the page, like on the screen, just before footer always. When there is text (from mergefield), next should be new lines. I hope screenshot make it easier to see.

Comment: You can add a footer, but this question don't belong to this site

Comment: I have a footer. I want to text before footer, at the bottom of the page. There can't be 2 footers i think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put the text in a text box or frame with position set to "Bottom
Relative to Margin". It's the only idea I have due you don't want to use a footer.

Or you can see [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/three-ways-to-display-text-in-the-margin-of-a-word-document/)

Basically it gives three options:

- Negative left indent
- Margin text box
- Anchor to the header

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the problem on Microsoft's page and I hope that this page comes up for as many people as possible.
Select the text you want to stick to the bottom (or top) of the page. Under Layout tab take a look at the bottom right of the page layout section and you should see a small arrow that, when clicked on, opens a new menu. In that menu, go to layout tab and set vertical alignment to be "bottom". IMPORTANT! Make sue that the next menu option (at the bottom of that window) is set to "apply to selected sections" otherwise, you will be writing from the bottom of the page upwards.
Here is the source image that helped me. https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/0382c4a8-ade9-4fc4-be66-bcd2c7101479?upload=true

Here is the visual representation:
[image: Here is the visual representation]

Note that the person who took the screenshot set the last setting to whole document, not just selected sections.

If selected sections option isn't available, make sure you selected a text before opening the menu.

Hope this helps!